# How to query Firebase database and not show values based of a boolean value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `FirebaseListAdapter` in Android to display a list of Orders based off a certain date:

```
Query orderQuery = ordersRef.orderByChild("dateCreated").startAt(d1.getTime());
```

My Orders have a completed boolean property

```
-KsRHO1sLcVxKtVMec3o
      completed: false
      dateCreated: 1503713136950
```

I would like to only show not completed items in my list adapter.
the current query above retrieves all orders.

The issue is I don’t know how to query the database correctly to get this to work.

The only idea I have is in the `populateView` method of the `FirebaseListAdapter` to check `if(!model.isCompleted()){ }` and not fill in the textViews associated with the list item.

What way could I achieve my desired result?

Comment: That means if your order is not completed then you dont want to show it list of orders. Is that correct?

Comment: try a custom adapter. it will be easier

Comment: yes @mzeus.bolt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in firebase there is not Multi Select or "Multi Query"

so you can **orderByChild**  creating time Or compeleted

So you have to use the Method You mention in your Question

```
    The only idea I have is in the populateView method of the
 FirebaseListAdapter to check 
if(!model.isCompleted()){ } and not fill in the textViews associated with the list item.
```

or you have to edit your database Structure

```
-completed
 -KsRHO1sLcVxKtVMec3o
       dateCreated: 1503713136950
```

and

```
 -Notcompleted
     -KsRHO1sLcVxKtVMec3o
           dateCreated: 1503713136950
```

like when it`s completed  .. remove it from notcompleted  Node and 
add it in completed   node

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use different references for completed and incomplete orders.

Initially when order is placed it will be in the `incomplete` state and when your `order` is updated then move the `order` with `key` in the `complete` reference.

Step 1:
Initially when order is getting placed, store the order in a "incomplete" reference like:

```
-incomplete:{
    -anyRandomKeyGeneratedByFirebase:{
       "orderTitle":"My First Order"... your order detail goes here
       "orderKey":"anyRandomKeyGeneratedByFirebase"
     },
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Above structure will be for incomplete order.

When you know that your order status is completed then you will have to move order into the `complete` child reference like:

```
-complete:{
        -anyRandomKeyGeneratedByFirebase:{
           "orderTitle":"My First Order"... your order detail goes here
           "orderKey":"anyRandomKeyGeneratedByFirebase"
         },
         .
         .
         .
    }
```

So in this it will solve your problem. Rather than fetching all orders fetch only completed orders from `complete` reference.

```
-orders:{
  -incompleteOrders:{
  },
  -completeOrders:{
  }
}
```

Comment: how would i go about setting this up? i wouldnt have it as a boolean within the model class.

Comment: I have added the structure please take a look